# Поиск по заголовкам постов и произвольному полю ( хук-фильтр)

Tags: php, wordpress

В интернете нашёл готовый фильтр поиска только по заголовкам постов. У меня  есть произвольное поле "production-year" Подскажите как я могу включить в фильтр ещё и его?

```html
function movieapp_search_by_title( $search, $wp_query ) {
    if ( ! empty( $search ) && ! empty( $wp_query->query_vars['search_terms'] ) ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $q = $wp_query->query_vars;
        $n = ! empty( $q['exact'] ) ? '' : '%';

        $search = array();

        foreach ( ( array ) $q['search_terms'] as $term )
            $search[] = $wpdb->prepare( "$wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE %s", $n . $wpdb->esc_like( $term ) . $n );

        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
            $search[] = "$wpdb->posts.post_password = ''";

        $search = ' AND ' . implode( ' AND ', $search );
    }

    return $search;
}
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'movieapp_search_by_title', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно, что имеется ввиду под произвольным полем. Попробую предложить, что это мета атрибут.

```
function search_by_custom_meta( $query ) {

  $search = isset( $_GET['production-year'] ) ? $_GET['production-year'] : '';

  if ( $search != '' ) {
    $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'production-year';
    $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = $search;
    $query->query_vars['meta_compare'] = '=';
  }
}
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'search_by_custom_meta' );
```

Comment: Почему-то ваш код не работает для моей ситуации. Думаю вместо того, чтобы пытаться изменить стандартный поиск мне стоит присмотреться к созданию своего по типу https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165478/creating-a-search-form-for-custom-fields

Comment: код приблизительный. не понятно как Вы передаете параметры на поиск. Также не понятно какой именно тип поиска нужен по ключу. Можно поиграться в параметре meta_compare - Может быть: `=, !=, >, >=, <, <=, LIKE, NOT LIKE, IN, NOT IN, BETWEEN, NOT BETWEEN, EXISTS (с версии 3.5), NOT EXISTS (3.5), REGEXP (3.7), NOT REGEXP (3.7) и RLIKE (3.7);` [ссылка](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query)